# How to custom display prompt in KornShell to show hostname and current directory?

Tags: unix, shell, environment-variables, customization, ksh

I am using KornShell (ksh) on Solaris and currently my PS1 env var is:

`PS1="${HOSTNAME}:\${PWD} \$ "`

And the prompt displays: `hostname:/full/path/to/current/directory $`

However, I would like it to display: `hostname:directory $`

In other words, how can I display just the hostname and the name of the current directory, i.e. `tmp` or `~` or `public_html` etc etc?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

From reading the [ksh man page](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/ksh/) you want

```
PS1="${HOSTNAME}:\${PWD##*/} \$ "
```

Tested on default ksh on SunOS 5.8

Comment: I was curious if the ##*/ is a common trick and have found this website http://cfaj.freeshell.org/shell/commands/ . it has some other useful shell tricks ;)

Answer (score 13):

Okay, a little old and a little late, but this is what I use in Kornshell:

```
PS1='$(print -n "`logname`@`hostname`:";if [[ "${PWD#$HOME}" != "$PWD" ]] then; print -n "~${PWD#$HOME}"; else; print -n "$PWD";fi;print "\n$ ")'
```

This makes a prompt that's equivalent to `PS1="\u@\h:\w\n$ "` in BASH.

For example:

```
qazwart@mybook:~
$ cd bin
qazwart@mybook:~/bin
$ cd /usr/local/bin
qazwart@mybook:/usr/local/bin
$
```

I like a two line prompt because I sometimes have very long directory names, and they can take up a lot of the command line. If you want a one line prompt, just leave off the "\n" on the last print statement:

```
PS1='$(print -n "`logname`@`hostname`:";if [[ "${PWD#$HOME}" != "$PWD" ]] then; print -n "~${PWD#$HOME}"; else; print -n "$PWD";fi;print "$ ")'
```

That's equivalent to `PS1="\u@\h:\w$ "` in BASH:

```
qazwart@mybook:~$ cd bin
qazwart@mybook:~/bin$ cd /usr/local/bin
qazwart@mybook:/usr/local/bin$
```

It's not quite as easy as setting up a BASH prompt, but you get the idea. Simply write a script for `PS1` and Kornshell will execute it.

---

### For Solaris and other *Older* Versions of Kornshell

I found that the above does not work on Solaris. Instead, you'll have to do it the real hackish way...

- In your `.profile`, make sure that `ENV="$HOME/.kshrc"; export ENV`
  is set. This is probably setup correctly for you.
- In your `.kshrc` file, you'll be doing two things

  1. You'll be defining a function called `_cd`. This function will change to the directory specified, and then set your PS1 variable based upon your pwd.
  2. You'll be setting up an alias `cd` to run the `_cd` function.

This is the relevant part of the `.kshrc` file:

```
function _cd {
   logname=$(logname)   #Or however you can set the login name
   machine=$(hostname)  #Or however you set your host name
   $directory = $1
   $pattern = $2        #For "cd foo bar"

   #
   # First cd to the directory
   # We can use "\cd" to evoke the non-alias original version of the cd command
   #
   if [ "$pattern" ]
   then
       \cd "$directory" "$pattern"
   elif [ "$directory" ]
   then
       \cd "$directory"
   else
       \cd
   fi

   #
   # Now that we're in the directory, let's set our prompt
   #

   $directory=$PWD
   shortname=${directory#$HOME}  #Possible Subdir of $HOME

   if [ "$shortName" = "" ]  #This is the HOME directory
   then
        prompt="~$logname"   # Or maybe just "~". Your choice
   elif [ "$shortName" = "$directory" ] #Not a subdir of $HOME
   then
        prompt="$directory"
   else
        prompt="~$shortName"
   fi
   PS1="$logname@$hostname:$prompt$ "  #You put it together the way you like
}

alias cd="_cd"
```

This will set your prompt as the equivelent BASH `PS1="\u@\h:\w$ "`. It isn't pretty, but it works.

Comment: Okay. It has been added.

Comment: thanks: somewhat shorter is PS1='$(print -n "`logname`@`hostname`:"; [[ "${PWD#$HOME}" != "$PWD" ]] && print -n "~${PWD#$HOME}" || print -n "$PWD";print "\n$ ")'

Answer (score 3):

ENV=~/.kshrc, and then in your .kshrc:

```
function _cd {
  \cd "$@"
  PS1=$(
    print -n "$LOGNAME@$HOSTNAME:"
    if [[ "${PWD#$HOME}" != "$PWD" ]]; then
      print -n "~${PWD#$HOME}"
    else
      print -n "$PWD"
    fi
    print "$ "
  )
}

alias cd=_cd

cd "$PWD"
```

Brad

Answer (score 1):

```
HOST=`hostname`
PS1='$(print -n "[${USER}@${HOST%%.*} ";[[ "$HOME" == "$PWD" ]] && print -n "~" ||([[ "${PWD##*/}" == "" ]] && print -n "/" || print -n "${PWD##*/}");print "]$")'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
PS1=`id -un`@`hostname -s`:'$PWD'$
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged because they do not explain how they resolve the issue. Please update your answer to explain how this improves on the other accepted and upvoted answers this question already has. Also, this question is 8 years old, your efforts would be more appreciated by users who have recent unanswered questions. Please review [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

and...

if you work between two shells for most of your effort [ksh and bourne sh]
and desire a directory tracking display on your command line
then PWD can be substituted easily in ksh
and if you use /usr/xpg4/bin/sh for your sh SHELL, it will work there as well

Answer (score -3):

Try this:

```
PS1="\H:\W"
```

More information on: [How to: Change / Setup bash custom prompt](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-linux-unix-bash-shell-setup-prompt.html), I know you said ksh, but I am pretty sure it will work.

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work as you've typed it. I'm fairly certain that what you've typed is BASH syntax. Thanks tho.

Comment: That prompt line produces more or less the desired result on OpenBSD 6 ksh. I'm using PS1="\h:\W " myself.

Comment: Works for me on ksh too.