# What does \ do in front of a command?

Tags: shell, command-line

Today I'm learning to install rvm Ruby Version Manager and saw that the instruction given on the [website](https://rvm.io/rvm/install/) look like this:

```
$ \curl -#L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --autolibs=3 --ruby
```

I'm wondering what does `\` doing in front of the `curl` command. I tried to google it, but googling `\` doesn't show anything useful. I tried `\ls` and `ls`, `\pwd` and `pwd`, both yields the same result.

So what does it actually do?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It prevents bash from using an alias. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15691977/why-start-with-backslash-in-bash.

Comment: thanks, seems like  duplicate to the question you posted. So I voted to close it as a duplicate.

Answer (score 4):

It says on the page that you linked to right under all the `\curl` links:

> Point to be noted is, there is a backslash before curl. This prevents
>   misbehaving if you have aliased it with configuration in your
>   shell start-up file.

Comment: Interestingly, that's not the correct answer. It has nothing to do with ~/.curlrc....

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I have edited the answer to better match reality.