# How do I call a function in bash if there is an alias by the same name?

Tags: bash, function, alias

Take a look at this example:

```
[boda]$ alias aaa='echo aaa'
[boda]$ function aaa () { echo bbb }

[boda]$ function aaa () { echo bbb; }
[boda]$ aaa
aaa
```

As you can see I've both alias `aaa` and function `aaa`. However when I execute `aaa` the alias runs.

How do I run the function instead?

Comment: Don't define the alias, or use `unalias` to remove it. [anubhava's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21738580/827263) is a good workaround, but the real problem is that you have a function and an alias with the same name, which inevitably leads to confusion. If at all possible, fix *that* problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> when I execute aaa the alias runs.

You can run it as:

```
\aaa
```

This will call function.

Comment: +1, where can find documents talking about the usage of `\` here ?

Comment: **In Unix shells, if an alias exists for a command, it is possible to override the alias by surrounding the command with quotes or prefixing it with a backslash.** As per: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_(command) also [check this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39291/run-a-command-that-is-shadowed-by-an-alias) or [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16506263/548225)

Answer (score 0):

The [man page for `alias`](http://ss64.com/bash/alias.html) reveals that there is an `unalias` command.

```
unalias aaa
```

If you run this, even after both the `alias` and the `function` have been defined, calling `aaa` again should run the function. This does, however, destroy the alias. If that's undesirable, then anubhava's answer (or Keith Thompson's suggestion to not define them with the same name) is best.