# Bash Script variable assigned "-r" when using rm -r $VAR

Tags: bash

Heres the code:

```bash
function rm {

    cd ~/

    if [[ -d ./Jam/projects/"$1" ]]; then
        echo Removing $1 from projects...
        rm -r ./Jam/projects/"$1"
    elif [[ -d ./Jam/archive/"$1" ]]; then
        echo Removing $1 from archives...
        rm -r ./Jam/archive/"$1"
    else
        echo $1 does not exist \in ./Jam/projects/ or ./Jam/archive
        exit
    fi

    echo Finished\!
}
```

When this is ran, $1 is "Hello World" (a Directory in i./Jam/archive/)

I get this output:

```
Removing HelloWorld from archives...
-r does not exist in ./Jam/projects/ or ./Jam/archive
```

Somehow, $1 is assigned to "-r".

I don't know how on earth this would happen. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I call a function in bash if there is an alias by the same name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21738526/how-do-i-call-a-function-in-bash-if-there-is-an-alias-by-the-same-name)

Comment: Unless you want to shoot yourself into the foot, it is a bad idea to name a function `rm`, in particular a function which changes the working directory (without changing back to the old one afterwards) and then deleting something there. But **if** you want to do it, you have to invoke the **real** `rm` by doing i.e. `command rm -r ....` to avoid a recursive call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function is called "rm" and inside your function "rm" you call `rm -r` thinking it's "normal rm", but it isn't - it's your function, which perfectly demonstrates the danger of calling your function a name that already has a well known meaning.

Comment: To be clear, the solution is to rename the function. In some other cases, you could use `command rm` or `\rm` (IIRC), but in this case, changing the command name `rm` is a bad idea.

Comment: Yep. I solved it a few minutes after I posted. Kind of disappointed in myself.