# How to grep lines with date formats?

Tags: regex, bash, date, grep

I have a log file that is created from a bash script that uses `$(date)`, so there are dates in such a format:

```
Fri Apr 24 22:10:39 CEST 2015
```

The log file looks like this:

```
Using SCRIPTS_ROOTDIR: /home/gillin/moses/scripts
Using multi-thread GIZA
using gzip 
(1) preparing corpus @ Fri Apr 24 22:10:39 CEST 2015
Executing: mkdir -p /media/2tb/ccexp/phrase-clustercat-mgiza/work.en-ru/training/corpus
(1.0) selecting factors @ Fri Apr 24 22:10:39 CEST 2015
Forking...
(1.2) creating vcb file /media/2tb/ccexp/phrase-clustercat-mgiza/work.en-ru/training/corpus/en.vcb @ Fri Apr 24 22:10:39 CEST 2015
(1.1) running mkcls  @ Fri Apr 24 22:10:39 CEST 2015
/home/gillin/moses/training-tools/mkcls -c50 -n2 -p/media/2tb/ccexp/corpus.exp/train-clean.en -V/media/2tb/ccexp/phrase-clustercat-mgiza/work.en-ru/training/corpus/en.vcb.classes opt
Executing: /home/gillin/moses/training-tools/mkcls -c50 -n2 -p/media/2tb/ccexp/corpus.exp/train-clean.en -V/media/2tb/ccexp/phrase-clustercat-mgiza/work.en-ru/training/corpus/en.vcb.classes opt
(1.1) running mkcls  @ Fri Apr 24 22:10:39 CEST 2015
/home/gillin/moses/training-tools/mkcls -c50 -n2 -p/media/2tb/ccexp/corpus.exp/train-clean.ru -V/media/2tb/ccexp/phrase-clustercat-mgiza/work.en-ru/training/corpus/ru.vcb.classes opt
Executing: /home/gillin/moses/training-tools/mkcls -c50 -n2 -p/media/2tb/ccexp/corpus.exp/train-clean.ru -V/media/2tb/ccexp/phrase-clustercat-mgiza/work.en-ru/training/corpus/ru.vcb.classes opt
```

Is there a way such that i can grep all the lines that contain the output of `$(date)`?

Currently I'm using this regex:

```
[a-z].*[1-9] [0-2][1-9]:[0-6][0-9]:[0-6][0-9] CEST 2015
```

And it catches line like

```
preparing corpus @ Fri Apr 24 22:10:39 CEST 2015
```

But i need the full line:

```
(1) preparing corpus @ Fri Apr 24 22:10:39 CEST 2015
```

And also the year and time is sort of hard coded. Is there a better regex or unix tool that can extract lines with `$(date)` outputs?

Comment: -o parameter from where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
unalias grep
grep --color=never '.*[a-z].*[1-9] [0-2][1-9]:[0-6][0-9]:[0-6][0-9] CEST 2015' file
```

Comment: this doesn't catch the `(1)` at the start of the sentence.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Which version of grep and which operating system do you use?

Comment: It removes an `alias` with additional options like `--color=auto`.

Comment: Note you don't need to `unalias grep`. To make `grep` behave circunventing the alias, just say `\grep`. See [Why start a shell command with a backslash?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15691977/1983854) for example.