# bash: if export PROMPT_COMMAND then remove rm $( ls -t | head -1) is not working

Tags: bash, shell

Below function `name` will set the the current working directory name as tab name using function `myfunc` but if I pass argument to `name` then it will set tab name to passed argument.
for e.g.
name mytab  [----> this will set the current tab name to mytab]

my bashrc is as follows :

```
function myfunc {  
echo -n -e "\033]0;${PWD##*/}\007" 
#--- some other thing ---
} 
function name {  
    if [ "$1" ]  
    then  
        unset PROMPT_COMMAND  
        echo -ne "\033]0;${*}\007"  
    else  
        unset PROMPT_COMMAND  
        export PROMPT_COMMAND="history -n; history -w; history -c; history -r; myfunc;$PROMPT_COMMAND"  
    fi  
}  
name
```

So if I execute `rm $(ls -t | head -1)`
    I am getting error as `` /bin/rm: cannot lstat `\033[0m\033[0mReadme.txt\033[0m': No such file or directory ``

Comment: can you show the output of `which ls`

Comment: `which ls`  >>       `alias ls='ls --color'`  
 `/bin/ls`

Comment: can you test the command `rm $(ls --color=no -t | head -1)`

Comment: Yes. it worked. Thnaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the following command

```
rm $(ls --color=no -t | head -1)
```

This outputs the result of `ls` without colors in it, which is what makes your `Readme.txt` to be shown, instead, as `\033[0m\033[0mReadme.txt\033[0m`.

Alternatively, you can circumvent the alias of `ls` by saying `\ls` --> `\ls -t | head -1`. More info in [Why start a shell command with a backslash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15691977/1983854).

Comment: Yes, worked gr8. I just changed it to `rm $(/bin/ls -t | head -1)`