# Am I able to deactivate verbose output in the bash?

Tags: bash, alias

I have aliases for many commands with their verbose flags, e.g.:

```
alias ninja='ninja --verbose -j 0'
```

Is there a mechanism in bash, where I can deactivate this flag afterwards?

I tried stuff like:

```
ninja --verbose=0
```

but that didn't work out.

I know that I can hide my output with `/dev/null` or that I can execute the binary directly with `/path/to/ninja`, but that's not the intent of my question. The answer might be command specific and depends on which mechanism for passing parameters the appropriate program uses, e.g. `getopts`. Anyways, I am looking forward to your help.

EDIT: 
From comments I learned, that `command ninja` or escaping like `nin\ja` will ignore the complete alias, but not a specific parameter.

Comment: I suggest `\ninja` or `command ninja` to disable alias for only this moment.

Comment: So these commands are equivalent and ignore aliases? @Cyrus

Comment: Aliases are ignored if any of the characters are quoted (for example using a backslash). [See also](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16506263/1016216)

Comment: Note that this only ignores aliases, not shell functions. Use `command ninja` to bypass both.

Comment: @L3viathan: I suggest to close this question with your linked question/answer.

Comment: This would answer my question for the ninja case, however with more complex aliases it doesn't work as all options are turned off and not only a specific one. In my example this use-case was not completely described.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why start a shell command with a backslash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15691977/why-start-a-shell-command-with-a-backslash)

Comment: @h0ch5tr4355 Some applications support overriding options by supplying the option again, but that depends on the tool.

Comment: This might help: `\ninja -j 0`

Comment: I don't know if this would help you out here, but one can also define aliases with arguments `alias echo='command echo "$*"'`