# What is exactly ".\" in zsh commands

Tags: zsh

When I was installing NVM through Homebrew,
I found it. The backslash seems to be escaping the dot.
Whey are they exactly doing before the shell script?

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
  [ -s "/opt/homebrew/opt/nvm/nvm.sh" ] && \. "/opt/homebrew/opt/nvm/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
  [ -s "/opt/homebrew/opt/nvm/etc/bash_completion.d/nvm" ] && \. "/opt/homebrew/opt/nvm/etc/bash_completion.d/nvm"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
```

Comment: There is no ".\" in this code; only a "\.". The backslash escapes the following character. However, in this case it is unnecessary. because a lone period in the position of a command does not have any specific meaning.

Answer (score 1):

Could be a line ending quirk, that interestingly does not change semantics.
I.e. the original code could have been

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "/opt/homebrew/opt/nvm/nvm.sh" ] && \
. "/opt/homebrew/opt/nvm/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "/opt/homebrew/opt/nvm/etc/bash_completion.d/nvm" ] && \
. "/opt/homebrew/opt/nvm/etc/bash_completion.d/nvm"  # Loads nvm bash_completion
```

and then the newlines got removed. Quoting the dot command wit `\.` has no effect other than suppressing alias-substitution. See also my answer to [Why start a shell command with a backslash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15691977/why-start-a-shell-command-with-a-backslash/16506263#16506263)

The code checks whether the files are non-empty and if so, sources them.

Comment: You've solved the question completely, thanks.

Comment: And neither backslash is actually necessary here, as a line ending with `&&` is inferred to continue on the next line.