# meaning of bash script cmd="${1-__missing__}"

Tags: bash

```
conda () {
    \local cmd="${1-__missing__}"
    case "$cmd" in
        (activate | deactivate) __conda_activate "$@" ;;
        (install | update | upgrade | remove | uninstall) __conda_exe "$@" || \return
            __conda_reactivate ;;
        (*) __conda_exe "$@" ;;
    esac
}
```

I think local means cmd is a local variable. But what does the backslash before local mean? And $1 is the first argument passed to function conda(), but what is `"${1-__missing__}"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a variant of [shell parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html). In this case, if `$1` is set, `${1-__missing__}` expands to what `$1` would expand to, i.e. the first argument passed to the `conda()` function. Otherwise, `${1-__missing__}` expands to the string `__missing__`.

> When not performing substring expansion, using the form described
> below (e.g., ‘:-’), Bash tests for a parameter that is unset or null.
> Omitting the colon results in a test only for a parameter that is
> unset. Put another way, if the colon is included, the operator tests
> for both parameter’s existence and that its value is not null; if the
> colon is omitted, the operator tests only for existence.
>
> **${parameter:-word}**
>
> If parameter is unset or null, the expansion of word is substituted.
> Otherwise, the value of parameter is substituted.
>
> ```
> $ v=123
> $ echo ${v-unset}
>   123
> ```

Some additional notes:

The paragraph right before the above quote states,

> In each of the cases below, word is subject to tilde expansion, parameter expansion, command substitution, and arithmetic expansion.

That means for example when `$v` is not set, `${v:-*}` will expand to the names of all the files under the current directory due to globbing, or the string `*` if the directory is empty. That means if you want to always obtain a literal `*` whenever `$v` is unset, you have to quote it like `${v-"*"}`.

Some forms of parameter expansions, including this one, is actually not limited to bash and is part of the POSIX shell specification. Maybe some people will find the following table from [the POSIX docs](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_02) clearer.

|  | *parameter* | *parameter* | *parameter* |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | **Set and Not Null** | **Set But Null** | **Unset** |
| **${***parameter***:-***word***}** | substitute *parameter* | substitute *word* | substitute *word* |
| **${***parameter***-***word***}** | substitute *parameter* | substitute null | substitute *word* |
| **${***parameter***:=***word***}** | substitute *parameter* | assign *word* | assign *word* |
| **${***parameter***=***word***}** | substitute *parameter* | substitute null | assign *word* |
| **${***parameter***:?***word***}** | substitute *parameter* | error, exit | error, exit |
| **${***parameter***?***word***}** | substitute *parameter* | substitute null | error, exit |
| **${***parameter***:+***word***}** | substitute *word* | substitute null | substitute null |
| **${***parameter***+***word***}** | substitute *word* | substitute *word* | substitute null |

Finally, when working with bash, I strongly recommend [this cheatsheet](https://devhints.io/bash), which covers most of the bash syntaxes.

Comment: what is the backslash before keyword local?

Comment: It is mainly for preventing `local` from being interpreted as an alias in the rare case that the user defines one. More info can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15691977/why-start-a-shell-command-with-a-backslash).